# Figuring out the time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am a student and learning about time complexity. I am stuck in a question below. i have searched for it but couldn't find anything related. Can any one can figure out the time complexity of below algorithm or just let me know that where to find the answer.

```
1:  procedure MysteryAlg(x , n)
2:      if n = 0 then
3:          return 1
4:      end if
5:      if n = 1 then
6:          return x
7:      end if
8:      if n is even then
9:          return MysteryAlg(x * x, n/2)
10:     else
11:         return MysteryAlg(x * x, n/2) * x
12:     end if
13:  end procedure
```

Thank You.

Comment: What does `n=2` mean? Does it mean to pass `2` as the `n` parameter? If so, the algorithm will not terminate for input where `n` is neither 0 nor 1.

Comment: Just guessing, but probably ```n=2``` should be changed to ```n/2``` considering the structure of the code and even/odd check.

Comment: yes it is n/2..

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you have written is named "Exponentiation by squaring". You can get more information from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Look at the section with title "**Basic method**"

And it takes O(log2(n)) operation. So you can take that as the algorithm complexity.